# Maven testing jobs memory allocation is expanding to 20gb on Jenkins servers

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jenkins, ram

I have a Jenkins server running maven jobs to test a web application, using java and selenium.

we had a lot of out of memory problems. Tried to limit the memory use with xmx, maxPermSize configurations etc, in the pom file and in the jobs 'goals and options' line, didn't help.

Upon further investigation I found that the surefirebooter processes of the surefire plugin are not letting go of the memory they use, as seen in the next graph:
[ram consumption over time along 1 day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRWlu.png)

what could be the root cause of that?

maven version is 3.6.0, jenkins 2.22, and java 13.

The project overall contains about 5,000 files. Each testng list contains about 50 tests.

Comment: First using most recent version of Maven as well as surefire the most recent versions and also using a more recent version of JDK...also how have you configured surefire ? Why not using failsafe for integration tests etc. ?